# How do I extract the UPCs from the output of the apriori algorithm?

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis

I have output from the apriori algorithm (package: arules) and I would like to extract the UPCs from this output? How do I do this?

The code that generated the output is the following:

```
i<- split(dg1$UPC.Code, dg1$Transaction.ID)

#View the result

head(i)

txn<-as(i,"transactions")

basket_rules <- apriori(txn, parameter = list(sup = 0.0005, conf = 0.0001, minlen=2,target="rules"))

inspect(basket_rules)
```

The output is the following:

```
lhs               rhs                 support confidence       lift
1   {51500764213}  => {51500605660}  0.0005765499 0.47621383 333.340972
2   {51500605660}  => {51500764213}  0.0005765499 0.40357440 333.340972
3   {51500763100}  => {51500601334}  0.0005118291 0.41522158 210.758865
4   {51500601334}  => {51500763100}  0.0005118291 0.25979506 210.758865
5   {644209412006} => {16000459601}  0.0005355798 0.44719881  99.662903
6   {16000459601}  => {644209412006} 0.0005355798 0.11935953  99.662903
7   {15300200029}  => {15300200012}  0.0005587368 0.31056106 151.209386
8   {15300200012}  => {15300200029}  0.0005587368 0.27204394 151.209386
9   {51500555071}  => {51500601334}  0.0005320172 0.36706268 186.314290
10  {51500601334}  => {51500555071}  0.0005320172 0.27004219 186.314290
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Have you listed the attributes of the returned object (`names(attributes(basket_rules))`), looked at the individual elements (e.g. `head(basket_rules$foo)` for attribute 'foo') or taken a peek at the code for `inspect` that generated the summary you've provided?